# PHP MongoRegEx and executeQuery returns all documents

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I try to `executeQuery` in a MongoDB Collection through PHP 7 with a complex filter :

```
filters:wp\Database\MongoDB\Filter\Filter:private] => Array
    (
        [$or] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [generic_name] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                            (
                                [pattern] => /^pain$/i
                                [flags] => i
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [generic_name_fr] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                            (
                                [pattern] => /^pain$/i
                                [flags] => i
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [product_name] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                            (
                                [pattern] => /^pain$/i
                                [flags] => i
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [_keywords] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                            (
                                [pattern] => /^pain$/i
                                [flags] => i
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [brands] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                            (
                                [pattern] => /^pain$/i
                                [flags] => i
                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [categories] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                            (
                                [pattern] => /^pain$/i
                                [flags] => i
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

but when i run the query, MongoDB returns all documents in the collection, means that the filter is not understand.

```
// this->queryArray is the array that contains the filter
$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($this->queryArray, []);
```

And the `executeQuery` invoke :

```
$this->cursor = $currentConnection->executeQuery("mymongodb.mycollection, $query);
```

After that, `$this->cursor` contains all documents in the collection, not those that contains (or begins with) the `RegEx`.

Don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Regards

Comment: Pretty sure the results actually contain "at least one field" that matches the conditions you specified. Which is what [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) does. If you believe otherwise, then you need to show a sample of data and the results obtained, and ideally the "expected results".

Comment: Just to add though `/^pain$/` which is matching both at the "beginning" and the "end" of the string, may as well be a simple "equality match". The only other thing here is the "case insensitive" modifier. But if you have MongoDB 3.4, then we can even work around that by indexing and searching with "collation" options that ignore the case.

Comment: I recommend to you start use MongoDB Library for PHP (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library). Then your life will be a lot easer.

Comment: Sure that the query returns all documents of the collection... really 322720 rows!

"count" : 322720

Just add a counter in my PHP code to check the counter.

So i'm quiet sure that my filter doesn't run as expected... But, in order to verify results, i will try to execute query with only one restriction (i.e only on the product_name key of the collection) and will check the results

Comment: I'm going further with my problem and see that my query is empty, so my PHP code returns all of documents.
I will try to understand why this behaviour

Comment: So... After further investigations, it appears that some of my classes returned bad properties, then, filters was incorrect.

Thanks all